# Regex giving tuple and not full match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use regex to find proxy address on a website. Currently I'm using this piece of regex `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:(\d+)`. It works on [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) and in sublime text, but when I try to use it in Python it doesn't work as expected.

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
p = re.compile("(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:(\d+)")
ipCandidates = p.findall(soupString)
```

It should return proxies like this `120.206.182.172:8123` but it returns tuples like this `('44.', '3128')`. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have those capturing groups? What did you expect them to capture? If you want non-capturing groups, that's `(?:stuff)` rather than `(stuff)`.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I found the regex online and it worked perfectly in everything but Python. I'm not very proficient with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall()` only returns the contents of capturing groups instead of the whole match (if you have such groups in your regex).

Then, you're repeating a capturing group three times, which means that only the third repetition is preserved (the other two are overwritten).

Change your regex to

```
p = re.compile(r"(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d+")
```

and you'll get whole matches.

If you do want tuples of the separate submatches (without the dots and colon), you can do that, too, but you can't use repetition then:

```
p = re.compile(r"(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}):(\d+)")
```

Also, always use raw strings for regexes, so regex escape sequences and string escape sequences can't be confused.